# Too slow to Copy the data from one sheet and paste in exact row of master tracker if it present in column in big excel file using FOR and Next loop

Tags: vba, excel

Thanks for accepting me in this forum.

I have a excel sheet which contains more than **90,000 rows** as master traker.

my code is

```html
Dim i As Long, j As Long, lastrow1 As Long, lastrow2 As Long
Dim myname As String
Dim mysegment As String
lastrow1 = wb3.Sheets(1).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To lastrow1
myname = wb3.Sheets(1).Cells(i, "A").Value
mysegment = wb3.Sheets(1).Cells(i, "B").Value
Wb2.Sheets(1).Activate
lastrow2 = Wb2.Sheets(1).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For j = 2 To lastrow2

If Wb2.Sheets(1).Cells(j, "A").Value = myname And Wb2.Sheets(1).Cells(j, "B").Value = mysegment Then
wb3.Sheets(1).Activate
wb3.Sheets(1).Range(Cells(i, "C"), Cells(i, "M")).Copy
Wb2.Sheets(1).Activate
Wb2.Sheets(1).Range(Cells(j, "C"), Cells(j, "M")).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
End If

Next j
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Next i
```

I need to update the Column C to K of master tracker using individual excel sheet which contains more than **1200 rows** *if the column A and B match*.

I have used For and next loop for this. 
However, it is taking so much time approximately 1 hour** to complete the task.

It will be grateful, if you resolve this issue.

Comment: You should add your code over here because such a long run for at first sight something that is not that greedy, it is because your code is not efficient and we are flying blind without it!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to disable screen update before `loop` :

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
```

And don't forget to enable them after `loop`, to let user modify the excel file :

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Comment: i have tried that. but still i am facing the issue.. the problem is my excel sheet is large one.. my code is

Answer (score 0):

### General Approach

1. Create a separate worksheet with a **Microsoft SQL Query** which make the
   relevant updates. OLEDB is significantly faster than VBA.
2. **Copy the separate worksheet** onto the master tracker.

***If this is not feasible (for some reason)*** and it's an **issues of code performance** you can try many way of improving code performance: see my post [here](http://www.analystcave.com/excel-improve-vba-performance/).

Last resort - VBA multithreading. See my post [here](http://www.analystcave.com/excel-vba-multithreading-tool/).

### Specific findings

Try modifying your code as follows:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False'!!!!
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual'!!!!

Dim i As Long, j As Long, lastrow1 As Long, lastrow2 As Long, myname As String, mysegment As String, ws2 as worksheet, ws3 as worksheet
Set ws3 = wb3.Sheets(1): Set ws2 = wb2.Sheets(1)
lastrow1 = ws3.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
lastrow2 = ws2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 To lastrow1
  myname = ws3.Cells(i, 1).Value
  mysegment = ws2.Cells(i, 2).Value

  For j = 2 To lastrow2
    If ws2.Cells(j, 1).Value = myname And ws2.Cells(j, 2).Value = mysegment Then
      ws3.Range("C" & i & ":M" & i)= ws2.Range("C" & i & ":M" & i)
    End If
  Next j
Next i

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic'!!!!
Application.ScreenUpdating = True'!!!!
```

### Further performance

I would "replace" the master tracker with a Microsoft Query simply writing a SQL like (draft):

```
SELECT Iif(IsNull(slave.A),master.A,slave.A), 
   Iif(IsNull(slave.A),master.B,slave.B),
   Iif(IsNull(slave.A),master.C,slave.C),
   etc......
FROM [Sheet1$] as master 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `C:\slave.xlsx`.`Sheet1$1` as slave 
ON master.A = slave.A and master.B = slave.B
```

This would be as fast as it gets. Probably a couple seconds maximum.
Feel free to play with my SQL Add-in to try: [link](http://www.analystcave.com/excel-tools/excel-sql-add-in-free/).

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have updated my question with my code. Please review and suggest me for resolving this issue.

Comment: @karthikkumar Look at my response.

Comment: I have used your code and i am getting method Range of object _worksheet failed as error. Plz help me out of this...

Comment: i got error msg when my code comes to this row "ws2.Range(Cells(j, 3), Cells(j, 13)) = ws3.Range(Cells(i, 3), Cells(i, 13))"

Comment: How bout replacing it with ws3.Range(Cells(i, 3), Cells(i, 13)).Copy
      ws2.Range(Cells(j, 3), Cells(j, 13)).PasteSpecial

Comment: i have replaced the row as per your suggestion. But still i am getting the same error.

Comment: try the above - it works for me. If not then do troubleshooting

Comment: @karthikkumar appreciate the +1 if this helped you

Comment: Thanks for your swift action. your code is running without any error. But still it is not copying the data and pasting it in master sheet. Please help me out this.

Comment: Can you please re-review your code and make it into  paste it in another sheet if if match?